# Dúvida com Update no Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update, crud

Desculpe pela pergunta, estou aprendendo Asp.NET com EF e estou tendo problemas ao realizar um Update específico.

Eu quero fazer um sistema em que haja transações em dinheiro entre contas. A parte estrutural está ok, mas o problema é o seguinte:

Quando eu realizo o primeiro update, o sistema faz a transferência normalmente, ou seja, ambas contas tem R$100,00, eu faço a transação de R$10,00, e uma conta fica com R$90,00 e outra com R$110,00.

Já na segunda transferência de mesmo valor, uma conta fica com R$80 e outra com R$100.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TransferCurrency(Usuario usuario, ViewModelTransfer viewModel)
    {
        if (usuario.Id == 0)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (viewModel.ForId == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        var usuarioTransaction = _context.Usuario.Single(c => c.NConta == viewModel.ForId);
        usuarioTransaction.Currency = usuario.Currency + viewModel.Transfer;


        var usuarioInDb = _context.Usuario.Single(m => m.Id == usuario.Id);
        usuarioInDb.Currency = usuario.Currency - viewModel.Transfer;

        _context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Alguém sabe a solução?

Eu sei que é bem básico, mas não estou conseguindo desenvolver a lógica.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na atribuição, ai que está o problema! pegando valores errados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema aqui não é a primeira, segunda ou terceira transferência... A questão é que nas operações você está atribuindo para os seus `_context.Usuario` o valor de `Currency` do objeto `Usuario` recebido como parâmetro da sua action e adicionando ou substraindo a quantia de `Transfer` da `ViewModel`...

```
    var usuarioTransaction = _context.Usuario.Single(c => c.NConta == viewModel.ForId);
    usuarioTransaction.Currency += viewModel.Transfer;


    var usuarioInDb = _context.Usuario.Single(m => m.Id == usuario.Id);
    usuarioInDb.Currency -= viewModel.Transfer;

    _context.SaveChanges();
```